# Must the costates be non-negative in an optimal control problem?

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

#### Constrained optimization

In pure optimization problems, one defines the Lagrangian as
$$\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda^\top g(x) \,,$$
where $f(x)$ is the cost function we whish to minimize, $g(x)\leq0$ are inequality constraints, $x$ are the decision variables and $\lambda$ are the Lagrange multipliers.
This formulation implies
$$\lambda\geq0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
with
$$
\lambda
\begin{cases}
= 0, \quad g(x) \lt 0\\
\geq 0, \quad g(x) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
being part of the optimality conditions.

#### Optimal control

In optimal control, one defines the Hamiltonian as
$$\mathcal{H}(t,x(t),u(t),\lambda(t)) = f(t,x(t),u(t)) + \lambda^\top(t) \, g(t,x(t),u(t))$$
where $f(\cdot)$ is a distributed cost, $g(\cdot) - \dot{x}(t)=0$ are the equations of motion and $\lambda(t)$ are the costates.
In this case, the optimality condition on the costate is
$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{ \partial x(t) }+ \dot{\lambda}^\top(t) = 0 \tag{2} \label{2}$$

#### Question

Given that the costates in optimal control inherit the principles of Lagrange multipliers in optimization, does the condition $\lambda(t)\geq0$ from Eq. \eqref{1} still apply to the costates in optimal control? Why so or why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition that the Lagrange multipliers must be non-negative only applies if the associated constraint is an *inequality*. If the constraint is an *equality* there is no such condition. This is true for constrained parametric optimization as well as for optimal control.

In answer to the question, the condition $\lambda(t) \geq 0$ does not apply for the constraint $g(\cdot) - \dot{x} = 0$, because this is an *equality* constraint. It is not because some property/principle is lost when one switches from contrained optimization to optimal control.